# 'can' in if-clause

Tags: modal-verbs, conditionals

Is it OK to use "can" in the if-clause of Type 1 conditional sentences?

For example:

> I'll try to find the audio files later. If I can't find them I'll record everything for you.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: @Ling.Please  down vote my answer and unaccept it.You may  get  a better answer than this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **I will try to find the audio files later.
>   If I can not find them, I will record everything for you**

You can use **can**\ not or **do**\not  in the if clause Type 1.There is no rule that prohibits the use of **can** in the probable condition.

Comment: Thank you! I have noticed that you corrected the first sentence. Shouldn't I use the article "the" before "audio files" if I am talking about specific audio files for a specific textbook? And why is "audiofiles" one word? My auto-correct is not happy about it. 

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Ling - This user has been leaving comments asking OPs to accept their answer. Such advice is in poor taste, and so we encourage you to **unaccept** the answer until at least a day or so has elapsed. See the comments and linked-to meta posts under [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/227753) for more information, paying particular attention to [Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307). You might also find [Are thanks for answers unnecessary](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4744) to be a helpful read.